# Adding a fadeIn effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I have this code, and I'm trying to add a fadeIn once the content.replace is fired.

I've tried quite a few ways, and can't seem to find the magic bullet.

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(link).parent().before(
    content.replace(regexp, new_id));
  }
```

:D

Comment: I guess you want to display the old content WHILE fading in the new content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var newStuff = $(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
newStuff.hide().insertBefore(link).fadeIn();
```

Comment: SLaks strikes again! :D Thanks so much friend